# How to listen to the events in web application (C# .Net)

Tags: asp.net

I have a third party application that raise event and send some data as an event args.
In the other hand I have a web application that need to listen to these events and collected data. 
Then there is an HTML5 page that access the web application via a resfull web request and get populate data on the UI.

How should the web application listen to the events and collect data and be ready for the html5 to make a call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [WebHooks](http://timothyfitz.com/2009/02/09/what-webhooks-are-and-why-you-should-care/), [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) and how to write questions that won't be deleted by the mods.